# Changing the name of JLabel in java dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a Swing program in which, I have to change the **JLabel**'s name dynamically in action performed block.

Comment: you can't. you can change it's text, though, by calling setText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JLabel is an object, the name you assign that data type will make the mapping between the memory allocated in the Heap and the object self, if you want to change the name, then re allocate the object by creating a new one, with a new variable name.

you can work with  collections

```
HashMap<String, JLabel> aWeirdLabelMap = new HashMap<String,JLabel>();
aWeirdLabelMap.put("anAlias0x00", new JLabel("myLabel1"));
aWeirdLabelMap.get("anAlias0x00");
```

another way:

```
List<JLabel> jlabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        JLabel buf = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            buf = new JLabel("label_" + i);
            buf.setName(Integer.toString(i));
            jlabelList.add(buf);
        }

        //later iterate or loop to find it
        JLabel c = null;
        for (JLabel jlabelList1 : jlabelList) {
            if (jlabelList1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Integer.toString(1))) {
                c = jlabelList1;
                System.out.println("JlabelFound -->" + c.getName() + c.getText());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any other way Xoce??

Answer (score 4):

You can rename your component in an ActionListener like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  myJLabel.setName("New JLabel Name");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I exactly did the same thing but, it isn't reflected in GUI.

Comment: You asked how to set the name of the JLabel. That's what I answered. It seems your question actually is "How do I set the text on the JLabel?" The answer to that is `myJLabel.setText("New Text");`

Comment: How to make that reflect in Gui?